# How can I implement python operators in PyO3

Tags: python, rust, pyo3

I'm trying to implement a vector class in rust for my math library.

```
#[pyclass]
struct Vec2d {
    #[pyo3(get, set)]
    x: f64,
    #[pyo3(get, set)]
    y: f64
}
```

But I can't figure out how I can overload the standard operators (+, -, *, /)

I Tried implementing the Add trait from std::ops with no luck

```
impl Add for Vec2d {
    type Output = Vec2d;
    fn add(self, other: Vec2d) -> Vec2d {
        Vec2d{x: self.x + other.x, y: self.y + other.y }
    }
}
```

I also tried adding `__add__` method to the #[pymethods] block

```
fn __add__(&self, other: & Vec2d) -> PyResult<Vec2d> {
    Ok(Vec2d{x: self.x + other.x, y: self.y + other.y })
}
```

but still does not work.

With the second approach I can see that the method is there, but python doesn't recognize it as operator overload

```
In [2]: v1 = Vec2d(3, 4)
In [3]: v2 = Vec2d(6, 7)
In [4]: v1 + v2
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-4-08104d7e1232> in <module>()
----> 1 v1 + v2

TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'Vec2d' and 'Vec2d'

In [5]: v1.__add__(v2)
Out[5]: <Vec2d object at 0x0000026B74C2B6F0>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As per the [`PyO3`](https://pyo3.rs/v0.6.0/class.html#class-customizations) Documentation,

Python's object model defines several protocols for different object behavior, like sequence, mapping or number protocols. PyO3 defines separate traits for each of them. **To provide specific python object behavior you need to implement the specific trait for your struct.**

Important note, each protocol implementation block has to be annotated with **#[`pyproto`]** attribute.

`__add__`, `__sub__` etc are defined within [`PyNumberProtocol`](https://docs.rs/pyo3/0.2.5/pyo3/class/number/trait.PyNumberProtocol.html) Trait.

So you could implement  `PyNumberProtocol` for your `Vec2d` struct to overload  standard operations.

```
#[pyproto]
impl PyNumberProtocol for Vec2d {
    fn __add__(&self, other: & Vec2d) -> PyResult<Vec2d> {
            Ok(Vec2d{x: self.x + other.x, y: self.y + other.y })
   }
}
```

This solution is not tested, For the complete working solution check @Neven V's answer.

Answer (score 2):

I'll add this answer to spare others from searching for hours like I did.

Using the answer provided by @Abdul Niyas P M, I had the following error:

```
error: custom attribute panicked
  --> src/vec2.rs:49:1
   |
49 | #[pyproto]
   | ^^^^^^^^^^
   |
   = help: message: fn arg type is not supported
```

It turns out that this cryptic error message hides two problems.
The first problem is that `__add__` should take values and not references, thus we remove the `&` before `self` and `Vec2`.
This allows us to get rid of the error message:

```
error[E0277]: the trait bound `&vec2::Vec2: pyo3::pyclass::PyClass` is not satisfied
   --> src/vec2.rs:47:1
    |
47  | #[pyproto]
    | ^^^^^^^^^^ the trait `pyo3::pyclass::PyClass` is not implemented for `&vec2::Vec2`
    |
```

The second of these problems can be revealed when we specify the type of `self`:

```rust
// DOES NOT COMPILE
#[pyproto]
impl PyNumberProtocol for Vec2 {
    fn __add__(self: Vec2, other: Vec2) -> PyResult<Vec2> {
        Ok(Vec2{x: self.x + other.x, y: self.y + other.y})
    }
}
```

This fails to compile with the errror message

```
error[E0185]: method `__add__` has a `self: <external::vec3::Vec3 as pyo3::class::number::PyNumberAddProtocol<'p>>::Left` declaration in the impl, but not in the trait
  --> src/external/vec2.rs:49:5
   |
49 |     fn __add__(self: Vec2, other: Vec2) -> PyResult<Vec2> {
   |     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ `self: <vec2::Vec2 as pyo3::class::number::PyNumberAddProtocol<'p>>::Left` used in impl
   |
   = note: `__add__` from trait: `fn(<Self as pyo3::class::number::PyNumberAddProtocol<'p>>::Left, <Self as pyo3::class::number::PyNumberAddProtocol<'p>>::Right) -> <Self as pyo3::class::number::PyNumberAddProtocol<'p>>::Result`
```

This leads us to the final working solution (as of June 2020):

```rust
#[pyproto]
impl PyNumberProtocol for Vec2 {
    fn __add__(lhs: Vec2, rhs: Vec2) -> PyResult<Vec2> {
        Ok(Vec2{x: lhs.x + rhs.x, y: lhs.y + rhs.y})
    }
}
```

Which successfully compiles under Rust nightly 1.45 and has been checked to work from Python.

It is also possible to have `rhs` of another type:

```
#[pyproto]
impl PyNumberProtocol for Vec2 {
    fn __mul__(lhs: Vec2, rhs: f64) -> PyResult<Vec2> {
        Ok(Vec3{x: lhs.x * rhs, y: lhs.y * rhs})
    }
}
```

Also note that having `self` is not always a problem:

```rust
#[pyproto]
impl PyNumberProtocol for Vec2 {
    fn __neg__(self) -> PyResult<Vec2> {
        Ok(Vec3{x: -self.x, y: -self.y})
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

These answers are out of date as of 2024. `pyproto` has been deprecated.
pyO3 docs now document this more extensively. A good example of adding an overload to a struct `Raster` is below. Note that `pymethods` overloads the native python **add** method.

```
#[derive(FromPyObject)]
enum RasterOrF64 {
    Raster(Raster),
    F64(f64)
}

#[pymethods]
impl Raster {
    fn __add__(&self, other: RasterOrF64) -> Self {
        match other {
            RasterOrF64::Raster(r) => self.clone() + r,
            RasterOrF64::F64(f) => self.clone() + f,
        }
    }
}
```